# Why only one record update in my table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have following table structure.

```
| A    | B   | C   | D      | E |
+------+-----+-----+--------+---+
| 1000 |   5 |   2 | 2018-A |   |
| 1001 |  15 |  63 | 2018-A |   |
| 1002 |  25 | 124 | 2018-A |   |
| 1003 |  35 | 185 | 2018-A |   |
| 1004 |  45 | 246 | 2018-A |   |
| 1005 |  55 | 307 | 2018-A |   |
| 1000 |  65 | 368 | 2018-B |   |
| 1001 |  75 | 429 | 2018-B |   |
| 1000 |  85 | 490 | 2018-C |   |
| 1001 |  95 | 551 | 2018-C |   |
| 1002 | 105 | 612 | 2018-C |   |
| 1003 | 115 | 673 | 2018-C |   |
| 1004 | 125 | 734 | 2018-C |   |
```

I need to update E column by multiplying B*C. In my stored procedure I tried following query, but it only updated the last row:

```
SELECT @A = a,
       @Ans = b * c
FROM   tbln
WHERE  d = '2018-A'

UPDATE tbln
SET e = @ANS
WHERE d = '2018-A'
  AND a = @A
```

Comment: I think you need to (re)visit the documentation about *scalar* variables. I can't work out why you're even using variables, why are you not just updating the table and multiplying B & C?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is your query...

```
SELECT @A = a,
       @Ans = b * c
FROM   tbln
WHERE  d = '2018-A'
```

...only initialises your variables `@A` and `@Ans`  with info from a single row. And only that one is updated afterwards
To update all, just use:

```
UPDATE tbln
SET    e = b*c
WHERE  d = '2018-A'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first statement you are setting `@A = A`. Given that column A is the primary key of your table it is uniquely identifying each row. When the first SELECT statement is done executing `@A = 1004`.

Then your UPDATE statement executes and is filtering for A = @A which is A = 1004.

If you want to update column E for all rows in the sample then you need to remove your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT @A = a,

Will only have **one** value at the end and so you will update only one row

What you need to do is followinf to update all rows with 2018-A

```
CREATE TABLE tbln
    ([A] int, [B] int, [C] int, [D] varchar(6), [E] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO tbln
    ([A], [B], [C], [D], [E])
VALUES
    (1000, 5, 2, '2018-A', NULL),
    (1001, 15, 63, '2018-A', NULL),
    (1002, 25, 124, '2018-A', NULL),
    (1003, 35, 185, '2018-A', NULL),
    (1004, 45, 246, '2018-A', NULL),
    (1005, 55, 307, '2018-A', NULL),
    (1000, 65, 368, '2018-B', NULL),
    (1001, 75, 429, '2018-B', NULL),
    (1000, 85, 490, '2018-C', NULL),
    (1001, 95, 551, '2018-C', NULL),
    (1002, 105, 612, '2018-C', NULL),
    (1003, 115, 673, '2018-C', NULL),
    (1004, 125, 734, '2018-C', NULL)
;
```

```
13 rows affected
```

```
UPDATE tbln
SET    e = b*c
WHERE  d = '2018-A'
```

```
6 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM tbln
```

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 5 | 2 | 2018-A | 10 |
| 1001 | 15 | 63 | 2018-A | 945 |
| 1002 | 25 | 124 | 2018-A | 3100 |
| 1003 | 35 | 185 | 2018-A | 6475 |
| 1004 | 45 | 246 | 2018-A | 11070 |
| 1005 | 55 | 307 | 2018-A | 16885 |
| 1000 | 65 | 368 | 2018-B | *null* |
| 1001 | 75 | 429 | 2018-B | *null* |
| 1000 | 85 | 490 | 2018-C | *null* |
| 1001 | 95 | 551 | 2018-C | *null* |
| 1002 | 105 | 612 | 2018-C | *null* |
| 1003 | 115 | 673 | 2018-C | *null* |
| 1004 | 125 | 734 | 2018-C | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PejhPejC)